# Navigating table by using th text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following table:

```
<table class="information">
  <tr> .... lots of rows with <th> and <td></tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Nationality</th>
   <td><a href="..">Stackoverflowian</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to find the text in inside the td tags under the th with "nationality" in it. How should I navigate there? I'm using Beautifulsoup and Python.

**Added that there is lots of th and td tags above this that, to underline that it isnt sufficient to just find first th**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the `th` tag, then get its [next sibling](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
ths = soup.find_all('th')
for th in ths:
    if th.text == "Nationality":
        print th.next_sibling.next_sibling.text

# Stackoverflowian
```

We need to do `next_sibling` twice because the first one will give the newline.

Comment: Doesn't this fail if the table header I want isn't the first table header in the html?

Comment: @bjornasm Absolutely. If you have multiple `th` tags, then you can find them all and iterate through them. I will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

I've modified this answer as you gave a specific HTML page you're trying to parse.

```
r = requests.get("http://https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usain_Bolt")
# test that we loaded the page successfully!
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

thTag = soup.find('th', text='Nationality'):
tdTag = thTag.next_sibling.next_sibling

print(tdTag.text)
>>>'Jamaican'
```

Comment: You should test your answer before you post it as a solution. While your method is correct, posting incorrect code will just confuse the OP and future visitors

Comment: This does not work with the following code:

           url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usain_Bolt"
  r = ur.urlopen(url).read()
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
  for element in soup(text='Nationality'):
   print(element.next_sibling())

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: When you define the soup, you need to give it actual HTML code to parse. In your example above, you are giving it the entire request object, r. Just pass r.text instead.

Comment: As you gave a specific HTML example of the page you're trying to scan, I can give you a specific answer. I've ammended my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking [for the table](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent) itself then consider `find_parent()`